# Flutter: accessing providers from other providers

Tags: flutter, provider

For my flutter project, I am using the following multiple providers below:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<FirstProvider>(
      create: (context) => FirstProvider(),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProvider<SecondProvider>(
      create: (context) => SecondProvider(),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProvider<ThirdProvider>(
      create: (context) => ThirdProvider(),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProvider<FourthProvider>(
      create: (context) => FourthProvider(),
    ),
  ],
  child: const MainApp(),
 );
}
```

Because sometimes I need to either get data or call functions from different providers from another provider, I am using it like this:

```
//First Provider
class FirstProvider with ChangeNotifier { 
  
 void callFunctionFromSecondProvider({
   required BuildContext context,
 }) {

  //Access the SecondProvider
  final secondProvider= Provider.of<SecondProvider>(
    context,
    listen: false,
  );

   secondProvider.myFunction();
 }
}

 
//Second Provider
class SecondProvider with ChangeNotifier { 
  bool _currentValue = true;

   void myFunction(){
     //Do something
   }

}
```

The `callFunctionFromSecondProvider()`of the `FirstProvider` is called from a widget and it will call `myFunction()` successfully, **most of times.**

Depending on the complexity of the function, I am sometimes experiencing that I can't access the `SecondProvider`, presumably due to `context` being `null`, when the widget state changes.

I am reading some documents online regarding `provider`, and they are suggesting `changenotifierproxyprovider` for what I understood as `1 to 1` provider relationship.

However, in my case, one provider needs to be accessed by multiple providers and vice versa.

**Question**:

Is there a more appropriate way that I can approach my case where one provider can be accessed by multiple providers?

EDIT:

Accessing provider should also be able to access different variable values without creating a new instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright.

So it looks like Riverpod by the same author is the way to go as it addresses alot of flaws such as Provider being dependent on the widget tree, in my case, where the underlying issue came from.

—--------

For the time being, I still need to use the provider and for a quick and dirty solution, I am providing the context of not only the current widget that I am trying to access the provider, but also passing the parent context of the widget directly, so that in case a modal (for example) is closed, then any subsequent provider call can still be executed using the parent context.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing `context` to the `callFunctionFromSecondProvider` function add the second provider as the parameter. So the function looks like the below.

*Not sure this is the correct way of doing that but my context null issue was fixed this way.*

```
void callFunctionFromSecondProvider({
   required SecondProvider secondProvider,
 }) {

   secondProvider.myFunction();
  }
}
```

Comment: I  am not sure if this is a correct way. I can see that you would be able to access functions this, but you are essentially creating a new instance of the class, and won't be able to access the original values of class.

Comment: when calling the function you can use ```callFunctionFromSecondProvider(secondProvider: Provider.of<SecondProvider>(
    context,
    listen: false,
  ));```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the info. Unfortunately, what you wrote is pretty much identical to what I have in the question, calling the provider via listen false. But although this will work, depending on the context state, it will fail.